# How do you split an array of sorted values into N arrays with max sum X?

Tags: php, arrays, split, sum

I have a large array with a bunch of integers in it, sorted from largest to smallest:

```
Array(
     0 => 472,
     1 => 388,
     2 => 211,
     3 => 194,
     4 => 175,
     ...
     29 => 13,
     30 => 6,
     31 => 3,
     32 => 3,
     33 => 1
)
```

What I need to do is split this array into separate arrays, with each array containing no more than a total sum of 'X'. So - assume that X is 1000:

```
Array (
    0 => Array(
        0 => 472,
        1 => 388    // = 860 sum
    ),
    1 => Array(
        0 => 211,   // would have caused first array to exceed 1000, so it is in here
        1 => 194,
        2 => 175
        ...
    )
    n => Array(
        0 => 3,
        1 => 3,
        2 => 1    // remainder of 7
    )
)
```

I have looked at `array_chunk()`, I have even tried iterating over the array using recursive functions - but am having trouble finding the best approach. Since some of these arrays could be somewhat large, I would like to do it in the most performance effective manner.

How would I split that array into chunks with a total sum each not exceeding X?

Comment: What about if one item in array exceed the limit (Like an example to be clear: first item in array exceed limit)?

Comment: That will not happen. This is for product data, and the size we are measuring are volumes. However - in the event that one volume exceeded the size of a box it was supposed to go in - it would be either a custom order, freight, or we would make it the only item in that box and charge a surcharge.

Comment: Have you tried looping and as you add the items up, if the next item takes you over the size then start a new list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked [Michel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61928275/11592056) answer, His answer is not contained last elements of array because of sum of last elements is lower than max so i added another condition to foreach for checking the loop iteration is ended

```
new_array=[];
$tot=0;
$new_chunk=[];
$max=1000;
$original_count = count($original_array);

foreach($original_array as $key => $value){
    if($tot + $value > $max){
        $new_array[] = $new_chunk;
        $tot = $value ;
        $new_chunk = [$value];
        continue;
    }
    $tot+= $value;
    $new_chunk[] = $value;

    if($key + 1 == $original_count)
        $new_array[] = $new_chunk;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do, I suppose.

```
$new_array=[];
$tot=0;
$new_chunk=[];
$max=1000;


foreach($original_array as $value){
  if($tot + $value > $max){
    $new_array[] = $new_chunk;
    $tot = $value;
    $new_chunk = [$value];
    continue;
    }
  $tot+= $value;
  $new_chunk[] = $value;
  }
```